# user unbound variable on docker run

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow

While running docker image, I am receiving the following error:

```
/entrypoint.sh: line 7: USER: unbound variable
```

Code of entrypoint.sh.

```
    #!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail

export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=$(hadoop classpath)
POSTGRES_TIMEOUT=60

echo "Running as: ${USER}"
if [ "${USER}" != "root" ]; then
  echo "Changing owner of files in ${AIRFLOW_HOME} to ${USER}"
  chown -R "${USER}" ${AIRFLOW_HOME}
fi

set +e
```

Declaration of Environment variable user in Docker File:

```
# Delay creation of user and group
ONBUILD ARG THEUSER=afpuser
ONBUILD ARG THEGROUP=hadoop

ONBUILD ENV USER ${THEUSER}
ONBUILD ENV GROUP ${THEGROUP}
ONBUILD RUN groupadd -r "${GROUP}" && useradd -rmg "${GROUP}" "${USER}"
```

Full code of Docker image is present in the [Link](https://github.com/datagovsg/airflow-pipeline)

Comment: You should edit and write the basic part of your code that may be faulty, for example lines 1-7 from `entrypoint.sh`. That will be easier for people to answer

Comment: @api55 Updated..

Comment: `ONBUILD` commands run, if your docker image is used as a base image for a derived build. You might need to add the same lines twice - once if `ONBUILD`, once without. (Not exactly sure what you want to achieve...)

Comment: If you end up here because of a similar issue in `bitnami/postgresql` chart, see this thread instead. It could be due to a dollar sign $ in the password.

`/entrypoint.sh: line 17: $4: unbound variable`

https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-postgresql/issues/213

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove spaces around the equal sign (=) in your .env file.
   Environment variable assignments should not have spaces before or
   after the equal sign.
2. Make sure there are no extra spaces or special characters in the
   variable names or values. Double-check for any typos or incorrect
   characters in the variable names and values.

Hope this works for you.